# Managing Views in UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

EDIT: updated code to accomplish what I wanted to do.

I have a table view in which i want to dynamically load an array of views into the rows.

For example, if there are two objects in my array: `{UITextField object, UIImage image}` I want the first row to show the text field and second to show an image. i don't know know how to refresh/manage the contents so they dont get added on top of each other. when I scroll, the images and text fields get added on top of each other as the cells are reused in the queue.

Lets assume my array of items is called arrayOfItems and contains the list of text fields or images i want to show.

Based on answers below, the code below worked.

```
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

for (id obj in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
    [obj removeFromSuperview];
}

[cell.contentView addSubView:[self.arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line before adding object to cell.contentView

```
for (id obj in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
    [obj removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Then add your object on cell.contentView like below

```
[cell.contentView addSubView:[self.arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

That may help you.

Comment: thanks. this worked, but i had to modify the rest of my code a bit.made changes above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should customize two different UITableView Cells.

and in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
if(row%2 ==0){
    // register your UITextField cell
}else{
    // register your UIImage View cell
}
```

I think this is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

give a tag to the subview, and remove it if the cell is reused:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle     reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
else
{
    UiView* view = [cell viewWithTag:1907];
    [view removeFromSuperView];
}
    UiView* view = [self.arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    view.tag = 1907;
    [cell addSubView:view];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always initialize the tableviewcell. This will clear/refresh the cells.

Use:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle     reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Instead of:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle     reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

I hope this will work.